# Removing the whole IDs with partial missing values in the data frame by R codes

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

In the following sample data frame (image), I want to remove all "pid_old" variables for the same numbers if there is a missing value in other columns related to the same ID, even for one year. For example in the 8th line, the value for "wage" is missing. Therefore, I have to remove all "pid_old" which are "2".
I will be thankful if anybody helps me how to write the code for this form of cleaning the data frame in R.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6NMw.png)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- tibble(
  col1 = c("a", NA, "b", "a", "a", "a"),
  col2 = c(1,2,3, 4, 5, NA),
  pid_old = c(1,2,2,3,4,4))

`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)

a %>% filter(
  pid_old %notin% (a %>% 
                     filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.))) %>% 
                     pull(pid_old))
```

Please post a reporducible example next time. You can do this with posting the output of `dput(yourdata)`.

Explanation:

Extract a vector of pid_old values which contain any `NA` values.

`a %>% filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.))) %>% pull(pid_old)`

Filter out the pid_old values which are in the above vector.

`a %>% filter( pid_old %notin% c())`

This line:

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

is credited to https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-notin-operator/